# lodash debounce not triggering

Tags: vuejs2, lodash

I am using lodash debounce inside several forms, which are rendered in Vue's v-for. My problem is the debounce has to be applied to all of them separatedly, but currently I am calling the method on every form `created` and that function is debounced across all the form components. Only the latest created one does the request.

The function is:

```
  import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

const debouncedValidateForm = debounce((vm) => {
    vm.$nextTick(() => vm.validateForm({ form: vm.form.uuid, data: vm.answers }));
  }, 1000);
```

It gets called in a watcher when each form loads its instance data. All the form components do, but as explained before all the components interfere with each other's debounce.

Comment: Hi, please show the actual code.

Comment: I updated with some code. Let me know if this tells you anything. I am assuming that this behaviour is caused by the debounce function sharing the same variable name across all form components.